# Expected payments by day given start and end date

Tags: sql, netezza, recurring-events

I'm trying to create a SQL view that gives me the expected amount to be received by calendar day for recurring transactions. I have a table containing recurring commitments data, with the following columns:

```
id, 
start_date, 
end_date (null if still active), 
payment day (1,2,3,etc.), 
frequency (monthly, quarterly, semi-annually, annually), 
commitment amount
```

For now, I do not need to worry about business days vs calendar days.

In its simplest form, the end result would contain every historical calendar day as well as future dates for the next year, and produce how much was/is expected to be received in those particular days.

I've done quite a bit of researching, but cannot seem to find an answer that addresses the specific problem. Any direction on where to start would be greatly appreciated.

The expect output would look something like this:

```
| Date    | Expected Amount |

|1/1/18   |  100  | 
|1/2/18   |  200  | 
|1/3/18   |  150  |
```

Thank you ahead of time!

[Link to data table in db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=9FIcCiMGDp) 
[Expected Output Spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2dmnjatnfdh85hu/Expected%20Output.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: Supply input data and expected results please. Bonus points for doing it on https://dbfiddle.uk/ , https://www.db-fiddle.com/ or similar

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @CaiusJard - I added links at the bottom for the table in db-fiddle and the expected output spreadsheet.

Comment: What's the database? The result greatly depends on the specific database engine.

Comment: I'm running it in Netezza

Comment: Hah, and here's me thinking the fiddle being set to MySQL meant you were using MySQL.. Now I've got some work to do to convert the mysql to netezza...

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying it earlier, and thank you @TheImpaler for adding the tag to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something like this, but I've never used Netezza

```
SELECT 
  cal.d, sum(r.amount) as expected_amount
FROM
  (
    SELECT MIN(a.start_date) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY NULL) as d
    FROM recurring a, recurring b, recurring c
  )  cal 
  LEFT JOIN
  recurring r
  ON 
    (
     (r.frequency = 'monthly' AND r.payment_day = DATE_PART('DAY', cal.d)) OR 
     (r.frequency = 'annually' AND DATE_PART('MONTH', cal.d) = DATE_PART('MONTH', r.start_date) AND r.payment_day = DATE_PART('DAY', cal.d))
    ) AND 
    r.start_date >= cal.d AND 
    (r.end_date <= cal.d OR r.end_date IS NULL)
GROUP BY cal.d
```

In essence, we cartesian join our recurring table together a few times to generate a load of rows, number them and add the number onto the min date to get an incrementing date series.

The payments data table is left joined onto this incrementing date series on:

- (the day of the date from the series) = (the payment day) for monthlies
- (the month-day of the date from the series) = (the month and payment day of the start_date)

Finally, the whole lot is grouped and summed

I don't have a test instance of Netezza so if you encounter some minor syntax errors, do please have a stab at fixing them up yourself (to make it faster for you to get a solution). If you reach a point where you can't work out what the query is doing, let me know

Comment: I'll try applying it and let you know how it works. Thank you!

Comment: If youve copied it in the last 5 minutes, copy it again - just tweaked a coupl of minor typos

Comment: For debugging, I recommend to run the subquery in isolation, for example, run just the CAL query and check it produces a long list of dates.. the rest of the logic really centres on the left join connecting the payments to the date list

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Caius! It definitely took me in the right direction. I'm actually creating a Calendar Table in Netezza and joining in my recurring information data based on your statement above. The calendar table gives me more flexibility, and then I can simply skip the part of the code where you're using ROW_NUMBER () OVER ... to derive future dates.

Comment: Great idea, and I should have suggested it myself - having a calendar/numbers table is one I've seen many pro DBAs do as a matter of course

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm no expert on Netezza, so I decided to write you a *standard* SQL that may need some tweaking to run on Netezza.

```
with
digit as (select 0 as x union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4
    union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9
),
number as ( -- produces numbers from 0 to 9999 (28 years)
  select d1.x + d2.x * 10 + d3.x * 100 + d4.x * 1000 as n
  from digit d1
  cross join digit d2
  cross join digit d3
  cross join digit d4
),
expected_payment as ( -- expands all expected payments
  select
    c.start_date + nb.n as day,
    c.committed_amount
  from recurring_commitement c
  cross join number nb
  where c.start_date + nb.n <= c.end_data
    and c.frequency ... -- add logic for monthly, quarterly, etc. here
)
select
  day,
  sum(committed_amout) as expected_amount
from expected_payment
group by day
order by day
```

This solution is valid for commitments that do not exceed 28 years, since the number CTE (Common Table Expression) is producing up to a maximum of 9999 days. Expand with a fifth digit if you need longer commitments.

**Note**: I think the way I'm adding days to a day to a date is not correct in Netezza's SQL. The expression `c.start_date + nb.n` may need to be rephrased.

Comment: When i tried to apply the code, I got an error stating that the "Attribute d1 was not found." Would that be Netezza specific?

Comment: My bad. Fixed the column name of `digits`.